# Validating HTTPS clients with certificates signed by other CAs than server's CA

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I have an apache web server, ssl on that has a server certificate signed by a trusted official CA. 
Can I configure apache ssl to accept clients with valid certificates signed by CAs other than the CA that signed the server certificate ?

I'm getting an `ssl_error_unknown_ca_alert` even though I have configured other CAs in apache and the server started with no errors.
I have created a file containing the CA certificate of the CA that signed the server certificate and the other CAs certificates of the CAs I want to trust. Then I pointed the  `SSLCertificateChainFile` directive to this file.

I'm using Apache 2.2.22

**Edit:**

I'm using 
`SSLCertificateFile` pointing to server certificate 
`SSLCertificateKeyFile` poiting to server key
`SSLCertificateChainFile` pointing to the certificate chain that signed the server certificate
`SSLCACertificateFile` pointing to a file with all the certificate chains I want to be accepted

```
SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth  1
```

Apache recognizes them all in the log when I restart server and there's no errors. Yet, I still got a `ssl_error_certificate_unknown_alert` error. 
I also verified that the client certificate chain is present in the `SSLCACertificateFile` by text comparing in Meld.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out what's the problem. The certificate is signed by a chain of 3 CAs and I set SSLVerifyDepth to 1. Set it to 10 and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want a directory containing the certs you want to use.  You may need to use some SSL magic to create the symlinks for the certificates.  See [mod_ssl SSLCACertificatePath Proper Usage or What is the Best way to Handle Multiple Acceptable Client Certificate CAs](https://serverfault.com/questions/249990/mod-ssl-sslcacertificatepath-proper-usage-or-what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-mult) for the required commands.

Comment: Well I tried these commands. See my edit.